# Why Bigquery deletes analytics data events after ten weeks?

Tags: google-bigquery

I activated Bigquery and firebase integration in november 2022

I created a simple sql request to count users per week adn year

```
    SELECT year, week_of_year, SUM(nb_download)nb_download #sum of nb_download
    FROM
    
        (
            #We get the number of people clicking on the button download
            SELECT
                DISTINCT EXTRACT (WEEK from (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date))) as week_of_year,
                EXTRACT (YEAR from (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date))) as year,
                count(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) as nb_download
            FROM `XXXXXX.analytics_XXXX.events_*` GROUP BY event_date
        ) group by year,week_of_year
```

In January, I had 2022 data and 2023 data.
I noticed today that now 2022 is missing. I only have 2023 data.
In the event, I don't have dataset for 2022, as if it is deleted.

What are the reasons please ? Why bigquery keeps only last ten weeks ?
[image]

EDIT
Found in analytics integration settings with bigquery that these data are kept only for 2 months of 14 months...it is strange. How to keep it always ?

[image]

I found in firebase the cause, how could i update this field ?
[image]

Comment: Would you check your dataset's default table expiration time first ?  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/updating-datasets#table-expiration

Comment: @Jaytiger `Table expiration    NEVER`   & `Default table expiration
    Never` this is what I have in the dataset detail.

Comment: @Jaytiger all data before the last 61 days was deleted...